# Getting values from .config files

Tags: c#, wpf

i write basic code, this is WPF project...

```
string a = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SetUserDB"];
MessageBox.Show(a);
```

but variable `a` is empty, why? im using `System.Configuration` on project...

my configuration file here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SetUserDB" value="RemoteDBHavana" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

now, have i can rename value on config file? thanks :)

Comment: Is your configuration file copied at the same folder as the executable and named like this `YourAppName.exe.config` where `YourAppName.exe` is obviously the WPF application executable? If the answer to this question is *no*, then you will have to make it so if you want this to work.

Comment: i have App1.config file in folder my project

Comment: That's a wrong name. If your executable is named `App1.exe` your config file must be named `App1.exe.config`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an executable called `App1.exe`, the configuration file must be present in the same directory as this executable and named `App1.exe.config`. That's the convention that .NET uses to load config files.

Comment: so, how i cam rename value in my config file?

Comment: A .NET config file should be used only readonly properties that are loaded once the application starts. If you need to modify properties you should consider externalizing them into a separate file or database.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - The config file name doesn't have to be of the same name as of your application. If app.config file name exists in your WPF project, it will automatically get copied to your output directory with the name ApplicationName.exe.config whenever a WPF solution is build.

Comment: Yes, but you are talking about a functionality of Visual Studio that does this. When you ship your application on the customer computer, that's how the config file should be named, no matter who/how it was placed there.